# Are there any non-recursive dataclass.astuple around?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

`dataclasses.astuple` is recursive (according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.astuple)):

> Each dataclass is converted to a tuple of its field values. dataclasses, dicts, lists, and tuples are recursed into.

Indeed, consider example:

```
In [1]: from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple
   ...: from typing import List
   ...:
   ...: @dataclass
   ...: class Point:
   ...:     x: float
   ...:     y: float
   ...:
   ...: @dataclass
   ...: class Side:
   ...:     left: Point
   ...:     right: Point
   ...:
   ...: side = Side(Point(2, 3), Point(1, 2))
   ...: astuple(side)
   ...:
   ...:
Out[1]: ((2, 3), (1, 2))
```

Are there any simple built-in way to obtain two-tuple of points i.e. `(Point(x=2, y=3), Point(x=1, y=2))` instead?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Well, I tried looking in the docs and googling :) Not to say I cannot solve this problem in some way (i.e. like your proposed solution or write my own function), but I used to believe that there should be some kind of canonical way to do it, as this use-case seem to be natural in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

There is no prebuilt way to unpack a `dataclass`. However, it can be easily defined:

```py
from dataclasses import fields

def unpack(dc) -> tuple:
    return tuple(getattr(dc, field.name) for field in fields(dc))
```

This can unpack any `dataclass` to a tuple:

```py
>>> unpack(side)
(Point(x=2, y=3), Point(x=1, y=2))
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach that uses the same core as MisterMiyagi's answer but makes the result a little more reusable and cooperative with existing python tools by leveraging the iterator protocol, consider this dataclass-specific mixin:

```py
from dataclasses import fields, is_dataclass

class UnpackDCMixin:

    def __iter__(self):
        if not is_dataclass(self):
            raise TypeError(f"This mixin is dataclass-only, which {type(self)} isn't.")
        return (getattr(self, field.name) for field in fields(self))
```

If you mix it into your dataclasses, you can just use the standard `tuple` builtin to turn instances into tuples, including any other tools that expect an iterable (such as `list()`, `set()`, or using it as the argument in a for-loop). And since the definition doesn't recurse into its field values, the resulting containers stay flat:

```py
>>> @dataclass
... class Point(UnpackDCMixin):
...     x: float
...     y: float
... 
>>> @dataclass
... class Side(UnpackDCMixin):
...     left: Point
...     right: Point
...
>>> side = Side(Point(2, 3), Point(1, 2))
>>> tuple(side)         # plug into container constructors...
(Point(x=2, y=3), Point(x=1, y=2))
>>> for point in side:  # ...or other iterable-contexts
...     print(point)
Point(x=2, y=3)
Point(x=1, y=2)
```